# Cleaning a list of names in Python for Data Science

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

so I happened to receive an xlms file that contains names of individuals with different titles such as Mr, Ms, Dr, Mrs, Judge etc. However some of these names contains multiple titles within one name example "Mr Mrs Ronderval", "Dr Rev Johns Mr" etc. So am trying to remove all of them except for one, hence the final result should be Mr Ronderval or Mrs Ronderval, Dr Johns or Rev Johns or Mr Johns any of them will be fine. So far what i have done is to convert the strings into a list of lists such as
`name_list = [['Mr','Mrs', 'Ronderval'], ['Dr', 'Rev','Johns', 'Mr']]` and have a list of titles `title=['Mr', 'Ms', 'Dr', 'Mrs', 'Judge','Rev']`. So i tried to iterate through the name_list removing all values from titles and the result obviously is "Roderval" and "Johns" but i want atleast one title to be left in the name Mr Ronderval or Mrs Ronderval, Dr Johns or Rev Johns or Mr Johns. How do i go about this?

Here is my code using list comprehension

```
 name_list=[[x for x in l if (x not in title )] for l in name_list]
```

Comment: Please add more sample data to your question which covers all edge cases.

Comment: Other data samples can contain other honorific titles such as Judge, Hon, Honourable, Prof  etc within their names, i just picked the most popular ones such as the ones in the title list. The idea here was to leave just one honorific title within each name. Unfortunately this is the type of messy data we deal with from time to time. Another case maybe `Elizabeth Jones Prof Miss` were i would want to remove either Prof or Miss and swap them to make sense, resulting in either `Miss Elizabeth Jones` or `Prof Elizabeth Jones`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna try `set` here -

```
result = [[name.intersection(title_list).pop(), name.difference(title_list).pop()] for name in map(set,name_list)]

# output [['Mr', 'Ronderval'], ['Dr', 'Johns']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nk03, this works as intended. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
name_list_all = [['Mr','Mrs', 'Ronderval'], ['Dr', 'Rev','Johns', 'Mr']]
title=['Mr', 'Ms', 'Dr', 'Mrs', 'Judge','Rev']
name_list=[[x for x in l if (x not in title )] for l in name_list_all]
title_list =[[x for x in l if (x  in title )] for l in name_list_all]

[x.append(y[0]) for x,y in zip(name_list,title_list)]
print(name_list)
```

**EDIT**:
Corrected code

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, when i tried this on my notebook it returns a list of nones i.e [None, None], i could be missing something

Comment: That's my fault, append() does not return the modified list, I pasted my first try which at the time was not running.

Comment: thanks this is also a good solution, just a note to others who might need to implement this solution that the strings would need to be swapped as the solution outputs   `[['Ronderval', 'Mr'], ['Johns', 'Dr']]`

Comment: Correct, if you want the title first you would need to change the syntax a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one pass through your name list checking to find a title and name (anything that is not a title) for each entry as you go.

Example:

```
name_list = [['Mr','Mrs', 'Ronderval'], ['Dr', 'Rev','Johns', 'Mr']]
title_list = ['Mr', 'Ms', 'Dr', 'Mrs', 'Judge','Rev']

filtered_name_list = []

for one_entry in name_list:
    title, name = None, None

    for name_or_title in one_entry:
        if name_or_title in title_list:
            title = name_or_title
        else:
            name = name_or_title
        if title and name:
            break

    filtered_name_list.append([title, name])

print(filtered_name_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Mrs', 'Ronderval'], ['Rev', 'Johns']]
```

Comment: Thanks @rhurwitz, this also does work as intended, however just quick question, how did you come about for your output to contain `Rev` and not Dr or Mr. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Depending on your perspective, it is either a bug or a feature of my example. ;^)  My inner `for` loop exits when it has both a title and a name, but each time through the loop it reassigns `title` until it comes to `name`.  As a result it always grabs the title that immediately precedes the name in the entry.